# How to update object in both array if I use separate array for search result?

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsobject

I want add search functionality in my listing screen. Every item in listing is not view-only but, say for example an object whose few properties are changing based on user action.

To add search functionality, the general way is to keep separate array for search result. Now, in my case user can either alter few values of object from either by searching or without searching. In that case, I will have to update object in both the array based on `id` of that object but this solution doesn't seems to be proper.

What is the proper way to update the model in this case?

> Here is my object

```
class Course : NSObject 
{
    var courseId      : Int = 0
    var name          : String = ""
    var chapters      : [Chapter] = []
    var estimatedTime : Int = 0

    // Values which will be altered
    var userSpentTime : Int = 0 
    var status        : CourseStatus = .pending // Enum

    init(_ json: Any?)
    {
        guard let data = json as? Dictionary else { return }

        /* Assignment of values from JSON */
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your objects type, class or struct? Could you share some code for how you want to use this?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson   Sure, I have updated my question..

Comment: Since classes are reference types you will have the same instance if you add an object to different arrays so changing it in one array will also update the other array.

Comment: Ok got it, thank you.. also I want to know if is there any way to manage it without adding conditions for `isSearch` true or false. In my case, at every place I will have to add if else condition for `isSearch`

Comment: Use one source/base array and apply `filter` to it in different ways when you only need a subset of objects